# How to connect to PostgreSQL server using encrypted password

Tags: java, postgresql, encryption

In usual scenarios, the connection string contains the password in plain text, but this can be captured by Wireshark, so I want to use the encrypted password in a connection string. I found the below excerpt from the Postgres documentation:

> **Encrypting Passwords Across A Network** The MD5 authentication method
>   double-encrypts the password on the client before sending it to the
>   server. It first MD5-encrypts it based on the user name, and then
>   encrypts it based on a random salt sent by the server when the
>   database connection was made. It is this double-encrypted value that
>   is sent over the network to the server. Double-encryption not only
>   prevents the password from being discovered, but it also prevents another
>   connection from using the same encrypted password to connect to the
>   database server at a later time.

If I understood it correctly, to get the salt, I need to connect to the database, but doean't that mean that the password can be spoofed?

I tried to google around but did not found a satisfying solution. I want to understand how can I get the random salt from PostgreSQL server using java and then encrypt the plain password with it and use an encrypted password to establish a connection.

Comment: You connect to server, before sending any login information the server sends you the salt, then you login with a hashed password. The client library you use should handle this, not you.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen you mean the postgresql driver inherently supports this. I do not have to do any additional changes other than calling usual getConnection?

Answer (score 5):

If you, user `arvind`, set the password to `secret`, the *actual* password is set to

```
'md5' || md5('secret' || 'arvind')
```

that is `md50624d6c2e831004efb7f4173699a1775`.  That's what you'll find in the `pg_authid` system catalog.

Now the establishment of a connection works like this:

**client to server:** I want to connect to database `mydb` as user `arvind`.

**server to client:** Ok, I want MD5 authentication. Your salt is `g73j`.

The client has been given `secret` as password.

First, it uses the formula above to get the *real* password (first hashing).

Then, the client hashes the password a second time using

```
'md5' || md5('0624d6c2e831004efb7f4173699a1775' || 'g73j')
```

**client to server:** the hashed password is `md573ae1f550fb4bcd28411cefb24b800bc`.

The server calculates the same hash and compares the result to what it got from the client.

If that is the same, the server knows that the client must have the real password, otherwise it couldn't have calculated the correct hash.

The password itself is not transferred, so it cannot be stolen by an eavesdropper.

**server to client:** Ok, you're in.

The actual messages look different of course, but that's all in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-flow.html#id-1.10.5.7.3).

Comment: is there any configuration needed for enabling MD5 authentication on the server side, or is it the default behavior? And if I understood correctly, this is happening behind the scenes, right?

Comment: You need to specify `md5` in `pg_hba.conf` for authentication to work like that. If you use a client library, the library will do that for you. If you want to speak to the server directly via network, you'll have to implement that yourself.

Comment: does all the postgresql versions support double-MD5-hashed password ? According to my research, postgresql 9.4 or above supports this.

Comment: Every version since the dawn of time has supported this.